# Does Spinal flexion really cause Disc Degeneration over long term?

Tags: lower-back, biomechanics

There is a popular claim within the medical industry that repeated spinal spinal flexion, especially in lower back, increasing shear forces on the spine can lead to disc degeneration and bulging in long term. I have met 5 physiotherapists and all said the same. Cannot provide a source for that but I can provide the source for claim made by Dr. Stuart Mcgill.

[image: This picture is from the book “Back Mechanic” by Dr. Stuart Mcgill]
This picture is from the book “Back Mechanic” by Dr. Stuart Mcgill.

Sitting jobs is one example where people can keep their spine (lumbar and cervical) flexed for a long period of time. Manual labour is other example where people usually need to flex their spine to pick up objects or for other reasons.

However, professionals like Dr. Greg Lehman and Dr. Adam Meakins have stepped up with claims, backed up with studies, that it is totally false. [[Greg Lehman](https://youtu.be/hiEyjpWuVdQ?si=P6PRi5FaWhuguhvG)] [[Adam Meakins](https://youtu.be/zgHUHFu3wCA?si=_WlLvFE3i3h4206c)]

But even though Greg Lehman presents studies disproving the relationship between lower back flexion and *lower back pain*, he still does not seem to be presenting studies all that much about relationship between lower back flexion and *disc degeneration*.

All the postural and biomechanical hypotheses causing disc problems are also being criticized, that 45 pound of head over neck causing cervical disc problems is just a myth, and that the discs actually have the ability to adapt and become stronger. And that perfect posture is a myth. Please correct me if I am wrong.

However, I am still not sure about the relationship between ‘spinal flexion’ and ‘disc degeneration’ (not “back pain” as “back pain” and “disc degeneration” are different entities).

I am not a medical professional but still my personal “unprofessional” opinion tilts towards that spinal flexion or the whole posture mechanics for that matter, should not matter to a great extent, if not at all, as spinal flexion is such a fundamental activity that humans have performed since the starting.

But it is all confusing. If studies are actually showing no relationship between spinal flexion and disc degeneration, why do many professionals still tell their patients that “Spinal Flexion causes disc problems” ?

What is your opinion? Is repeated spinal flexion really harmful over the long term? What weightage does the *mass of load*, *range of flexion*,and *frequency of flexion*  have? Does the effect of sitting jobs on disc degeneration have anything to do with spinal flexion or is it more due to sustained lack of movement?

Comment: Your personal opinion says it all, doesn't it? Is rounding the lower back (deep squat does  involve 10 degrees flexion no matter what) bad *if you move loads way beyond your usual and/or in unusual ways*? Well, yeah, that's how acute prolapses happen. That being said, disc degeneration is a fuzzy term. Main risk factor is, you know, age.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking Then why all (7) physios I met said that it is a bad thing? Who do I trust? Why does Stuart Mcgill say that? He is obviously not that stupid that he must not have heard the counterargument against preventing back flexion and not thought about it. I have 5 dehydrated discs in cervical spine, 2 bulging disc, and 1 dehydrated+ bulging disc in lumbar spine. I want to know why it happened and how I can prevent it. I never lifted anything too heavy. Is it because I sit with my lower back flexed and use phone with neck flexed? Until I fix the causes, how can I expect it to not worsen?

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking And I am just 19.

Comment: Dehydration comes from lack of movement. If you keep any joint (and especially the spine!) in any fixed position for more than a few minutes, let alone hours, with load (ie. for the spine anything not laying down), the cartilage does not get pressure differences and hence does not get nutrients. That's why cartilage and discs degenerate. What also is true is that when you lift weights *your spine is not used to in flexed position*, the risk of hibernation and buldging is high. But what Lehman, Meakins, and even McGill still hold is that *given proper training and adaptation*, it is safe to do.

Comment: Btw the above is not entirely correct: lack of movement and nutrition is *one* mechanism for degeneration. The other one is shear forces, which these structures do not tolerate well and start a degenerative cascade in the tissue. That's a whole different matter though. Lehman and Meakins are on the "nocebos produce pain" camp (which is perfectly valid), McGill talks mainly about either extreme loads (powerlifting etc.) or already pathological spines. You need to read the context. There is no general "X is bad". The body is *built for movement and loads*, not staring on screens.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking You have no idea how much I appreciate you explaining this to me. I have so many questions that I cannot just have a peaceful mind if they are not answered, physios just do not answer at all, and this makes me frustrated. One thing I did not understand is that you said Lack of movement is a mechanism for degeneration, no doubt about that. But you said that shear forces are also one mechanism, doesn’t that prove that flexing lower back leads to degeneration?